# Run java -jar and also specify the configuration path

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

A standalone(spring boot)jar can be run like this:

> java -jar springboot.jar

How can I configure the configuration path as well in the command above ?

Like this below: ?

> java -jar springboot.jar --configuration:/some-path-here

n.b. My configuration is external.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, Spring Boot will look in the working directory for external `application.properties` and `application.yml` files. For example, if you start your Spring Boot app in the same directory as the JAR:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Then this will look for `application.properties` (or `application.yml` or `application-{profile}.properties` etc.) in the same directory as your JAR file. This means if you set up your directory like so:

```
myapp/
| - myapp.jar
| - application.properties
```

And start the app within that directory, then it will automatically pick up the application.properties there.

If this isn't an option for you, the `spring.config.location` property can be specified on the command to give it additional locations to use when looking for configuration files, e.g.:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.location=file:/etc/myapp/
```

For more info, read up on Spring Boot's [Externalized Configuration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Answer (score 1):

[As per Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

`java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties`

Use `file` instead of `classpath` to specify external configuration file.